# Bash variable doesn't work inside compound evaluation

Tags: bash

Thanks in advance for your help with this problem that seems simple but I have not been able to fix. The following code is self explanatory of the situation:

```
    #INPUTS
    PID=8255
    echo PID is $PID

    #WORKING REFERENCE (THIS WORSKS!)
    GPID=$(ps fxao pid,ppid,pgid,comm |awk '$1 == "8255"'| awk '{print $3}')
    echo GPID is $GPID

    #TAKE 1 (DOES NOT WORK)
    GPID1=$(ps fxao pid,ppid,pgid,comm |awk '$1 == "$PID"'| awk '{print $3}')
    echo GPID1 is $GPID1

    #TAKE 2 (DOES NOT WORK)
    GPID2=$(ps fxao pid,ppid,pgid,comm |awk '$1 == "$($PID)"'| awk '{print $3}')
    echo GPID2 is $GPID2
```

The output of the execution:

```
PID is 8255
GPID is 8251
GPID1 is
GPID2 is
```

Comment: because there is no interpolation in single quotes!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc. Per your suggestion I've just tried and returned: awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence `\$' treated as plain `$'.  with an empty result :-(

Comment: tell you a trick. if you are puzzled about what your script is doing, put `set -x` on top if it, and `set +x` whenever you want to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks HuStmoHrrr; what change do you suggest I should apply? At the end what I need is to get the GROUP ID of the PID process.

Comment: besides the answer you have down there, another way of doing it can be `'$1 == "'$PID'"'`.

Comment: As an aside, `awk 'condition' | awk '{ action }'` is obviously better written `awk 'condition { action }'`

Comment: Thanks tripleee :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give it a value param per the docs page: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Shell-Variables

```
PID=8255
echo PID is $PID
GPID1=$(ps fxao pid,ppid,pgid,comm | awk -v d1="$PID" '$1 == d1'| awk '{print $3}')
echo GPID1 is $GPID1
```

Comment: THANK YOU. this solved the issue!